# PHP web-scrapyng

Tags: php, web-scraping

I would like for PHP string variable all url.

```
    $html = '<body>...<a href="foo-1">more</a>...<a href="foo-2">more</a>...<a href="foo-3">more</a>...<a href="foo-4">more</a></body>';
    // ?
```

Alltime "more" this "a" element content. I need: array ( 'foo-1', 'foo-2', 'foo-3', 'foo-4' );

Answer (score 1):

For web scraping in PHP, I would suggest using [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte).

It's a dedicated PHP screen scraping component. Does all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific

You can scrape a website using [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

The documentation is straight forward